# How to get current date and timezone of sftp server (date command is not working)

Tags: linux, sftp

I have an sftp server which I used to login using linux terminal using following method:

> sftp username@ipofsever

There are files with datename, I just wanted to know the current date & time and timezone of the sftp server.
The output of ***date*** command is :

```
sftp> date
Invalid command.
sftp>
```

*How can I see the current datetime on the server.*

Comment: This question is not suitable for Stack overflow, it may be suitable more in serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to retrieve the current time on an SFTP server.

---

Though if you have a shell access, you can use a respective command of the shell (like `date` on *nix systems):

```
ssh username@example.com date
```